# Why is the private variable assigned twice in this example of encapsulation?

Tags: javascript, oop, encapsulation

In this [example of encapsulation](http://gosukiwi.svbtle.com/object-oriented-javascript), why is `name` assigned to the private variable `_name` on line 9? It seems redundant to me, since in line 2, `name` was already assigned to `_name` and there haven't been any changes to `_name` or `name`..

Or am I reading this wrong and is `name` the private variable?

```
function Person(name) {
    var _name = name;
    return {
        name: function (name) {
            if(!name) {
                return _name;
            }

            _name = name;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two** `name`s. One is a parameter to `function Person`, and denotes the value `_name` is created and initialized with. The second is a parameter to the anonymous `function` stored as `name` member of the object, and it's the parameter passed to the getter/setter to update the value of the private variable (or get the current value if not supplied). Consider:

```
var someone = new Person("alice");
someone.name("bob");
console.log(someone.name()); // output: bob
```

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly: the `if` part of the function is the getter, the part below the `if` is the setter, the part outside of `return` is for creating a new instance and the anonymous function is to keep `_name` private. Is that right?